# NVIDIA 390 driver install hangs, and fails to install on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 18.04, dpkg

Installing nvidia drivers on my new Thinkpad dualboot option UbunutStudio18.4 FAILS

Here is the command-line log, as I tried to follow a couple of tutorials:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.1) ... update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-24-lowlatency Setting up nvidia-dkms-390 (390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ... update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated) INFO:Enable nvidia DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude Removing old nvidia-390.67 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning -------- 
Module: nvidia Version: 390.67
Kernel: 4.15.0-24-lowlatency (x86_64)

Status: This module version was INACTIVE for this kernel. depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

Deleting module version: 390.67
completely from the DKMS tree.

Done. Loading new nvidia-390.67 DKMS files... Building for 4.15.0-24-lowlatency Building for architecture x86_64 Building initial module for 4.15.0-24-lowlatency
```

I researched lowlatency kernel and find it very confusing. My dual boot login screen offers me that choice of kernel, and one called simply 'Ubuntu' i assume is generic? Neither kernel solves my problem. I am flabberghasted and sleepless now after one night of trying my best, obviously not good enough.

Any help with this problem will get me up and running on Ubuntu as a newbie intent on learning the commands and system for video and audio work.

Answer (score 2):

It might be the problem with your secure boot when installing nvidia-390 the first time. When you use nvidia-390 using `sudo apt install nvidia-390` for the first time it will ask you to perform a Secure Boot disable upon reboot (if you enable Secure Boot, which you probably have because I have this problem before). After doing so, when u reboot back into grub, it will ask to add a MOK key into the file then u will be able to successfully install the drivers.

My suggestion is that if you don't have anything on your Ubuntu you should do a fresh reinstall 18.04 because I don't know other way to fix this problem.

The same statement applies with .run file from NVIDIA page

I hope I can help you some way. I just want to ask to u experience login loop after installing nvidia-390 drivers because I have it.

Thank you